# How to Overwrite a File Object value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a  function, which essentially takes a File Object from an array, and duplicates it with a few adjustments:

`i` is the array index

```
  duplicate(i) {
    const arr = [...this.state.files];
    console.log(arr[i].color) //red

    let name = arr[i].name.slice(0, -4);
    name = `${name}-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1}.png`;

    const newFile = new File([""],name)
    const index = i + 1;

    arr.splice(index, 0, newFile)
    arr[i+1].id = Math.random().toString(32);
    arr[i+1].color = arr[i].color //set the color to red
    arr[i+1].preview = arr[i].preview;
    console.log(arr[i+1]) //color in arr is now black (the default color)
    this.setState({
      files: arr
    })
  }
```

What is happening is that the File Object gets recreated into the array, and then I successfully give it a new name, an id and a preview value.

I attempt to assign the color value, but this fails because color is already a value in the object.

How do I overwrite the existing value?

Comment: I don't see any of those attributes in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: Did you try using `Object.defineProperty(arr[i+1],'color', { value: arr[i].color })`?

Comment: What browser are you using? When I use `new File()` in Chrome, there's no `color` property.

Comment: What does the color of a `File` object even mean?

Comment: Maybe it should be `.style.color`, to set the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The `File` constructor allows you to provide optional attributes when creating it. Try putting all your attributes there rather than changing them later.

```
const newFile = new File([""], name, {
    id: Math.random().toString(32),
    color: arr[i].color,
    preview: arr[i].preview
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Thats a better way of doing it, but  unfortunately still suffers the same problem

Comment: None.  Thats the thing. It just doesn't override the existing colour

Comment: If it's a const, is it even possible to modify the color with a non-const value?

Comment: Annoying, I actually just noticed that your code doesn't set anything at all :(

Comment: @nixkuroi `const` applies to the variable, not the object.

Comment: OK. I think i've figured out what is going wrong here. I'm using React which modifies each array object, and I am doing `this.props.file.color` which gives the File Object itself a color parameter.  Doing `arr[i+1].color` does not add a color to the File Object itself, only the Object in the array if that makes sense?

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, so I don't really know what the implications of that are.